# how to redirect to www while also changing document root folder in htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to create the following rules in .htaccess ? 
Mod rewrite is enabled. But I am running into problems.

For each of the rules in each case (1) and (2) I want them to apply to the domains under that rule.

```
Currently all domains point to /public_html/. The .htaccess file is in /public_html/.htaccess.

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

1. Set /public_html/web/ as root path!
2. Redirect always to https://www, keep URL and parameters!

domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

1. Set /public_html/live/ as root path!
2. Redirect always everything to https://www.domain4.net, keep URL and parameters!

domain4.net
domain5.com

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

1. Set /public_html/staging/ as root path!
2. Redirect always everything to  https://www.domain6.com, keep URL and parameters!

domain6.com
domain7.com
domain8.com
domain9.com

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

1. Keep /public_html/ as root path!
2. Redirect always everything to https://www.domain10.com, keep URL and parameters!

domain10.com
domain11.com
domain12.com
```

When I attempt to solve with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Whenever the URL is accessed it shows the subfolder in the URL which is not what I want!

I found the following from siteground: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_change_my_document_root_folder_using_an_htaccess_file/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

and tried simply changing this as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain1.com/folder/$1 [L]
```

But this also shows the subfolder in the URL.

Comment: For #2 and #3, why are you concerned about the "root path" when you are redirecting to an entirely different domain? (Or do you have 5 domains pointing to the same host??)

Comment: yes exactly all the domains are on the same host, and I'm using one htaccess file for all domains

Comment: Gary, you probably want to set up `name based virtual hosts` instead, which will let you use the regular apache config to do things like set different `DocumentRoot` directives, etc.  Separating things out into separate vhosts will simplify many things, including what appears to be a needlessly overly complex `.htaccess` file/scheme

Comment: unfortunately there is no access to the conf's on this server, so I need to achieve with .htaccess

Comment: So, for #2 it's really `domain2.com` _and_ `domainzyx.net` for which you need to set the (virtual) root to `/live/`?

Comment: I tried to simply the question as it was more complicated than I posted.. but I think I've lost something in translation. Could you please check the updated question which should explain things better I hope @MrWhite

Comment: Rather than trying to do all that from a `.htaccess` file, simply set up individual virtual host entries for the domains that you're using and then add the logic you want to those virtual hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments on your attempts...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
> RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
> ```

These directives are in the wrong order. The *redirect* needs to go first in order to prevent the `/web` subdirectory being exposed. However, in its current incarnation, this would result in a redirect loop as it simply redirects to itself again and again... (I guess maybe the exemplified code introduced this "redirect loop"?).

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain1.com/folder/$1 [L]
> ```

Rewriting to an absolute URL (ie. with scheme + hostname) will implicitly trigger an external redirect and therefore expose the "hidden" subdirectory. You need to keep the redirect (to `www.domain1.com`) and the rewrite to `/folder` as separate rules - these are two different tasks.

---

My first thought is to treat this as one system. All redirects first, followed by the rewrites. I'll treat the redirect to `www` as the general case, so I'll include this last.

NB: Test with 302 (temporary) redirects first in order to avoid potential caching issues and only change to 301 (permanent) once you have confirmed everything works OK.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

#
# CANONICAL REDIRECTS
#

# Canonicalise www.domain4.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain4\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain5\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain4.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Canonicalise www.domain6.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain6\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain7\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain8\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain9\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain6.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Canonicalise www.domain10.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain10\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain11\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain12\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain10.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect to www subdomain all other domains
# NB: If you have other domains that shouldn't be redirected OR other subdomains
#     then you will need to explicitly check the hostnames as above.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#
# INTERNAL REWRITES
# NB: Since the request has already been canonicalised (above)
#     We only need to check the canonical hostnames below.
#

# Rewrite to /live
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain4\.net
RewriteRule !live/ /live%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite to /staging
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain6\.com
RewriteRule !staging/ /staging%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite to /web
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !web/ /web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Keep root as the document root for all remaining domains...
```

This assumes you are already handling the HTTP to HTTPS redirection elsewhere in your config (preferably *before* these directives).

However, this is not necessarily complete, as the user could still potentially access the `/web`, `/live` or `/staging` subdirectories directly (for *any* domain) if they are known. This is probably not an issue if this is a new system where these subdirectories have not yet been exposed. Additional redirects can be implemented to canonicalise this if required. Although, if you have additional `.htaccess` files in these subdirectories then this redirect would need to be included in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file instead.

Just to clarify, this doesn't "change the *document root* folder" - that is only possible by changing the server config. This is simply a URL rewrite that hides the subdirectory. The application still sees the document root as defined by the server config, ie. `/public_html/`.

**UPDATE:**

If you do not already have a general HTTP to HTTPS redirect then you should add a separate redirect at the top of the `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This redirects from HTTP to HTTPS *on the same host* (which is actually a requirement should you ever implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)). The redirects that follow then canonicalise the `www` subdomain as required.

If you have no intention to implement HSTS then you could combine the HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www redirects into one. And then *remove* the non-www to www that is currently at the end of the redirect block. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks MrWhite this was very helpful! I had to move the redirect for all other domains to the top, because otherwise if a domain was entered like "http://www.domain10.com" prefaced with 'http'://www. it did not redirect to the https version , but since moving the global www rewrite to the top it's working now it seems! Thank you

Comment: "I had to move the redirect for all other domains to the top" - No, that would be an error. It would not redirect `http://www.domain10.com` - since it has the www subdomain prefix. As stated below the code block, this code assumes you already have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect in place. If not, then you'll need an additional redirect. I'll update my answer....

Comment: NB: In comments, use backticks to surround inline code and URLs.